# How to Reset Autoswitch (setInterval) When Next/Previous Buttons are Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Currently, my slider is Autoswitching slides, which works great. But when you start clicking the next/previous buttons, it doesn't reset the interval speed which can get janky. How might I set the interval to reset when the next/previous buttons are clicked?

See my functioning example here: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/JKDESIGN44/pen/xxjvqPw)

And here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // options
    var speed = 1000; //transition speed - fade
    var autoswitch = true; //auto slider options
    var autoswitch_speed = 8000; //auto slider speed

    // add first initial active class
    $(".slide").first().addClass("active");

    // hide all slides
    $(".slide").hide;

    // show only active class slide
    $(".active").show();

    // Next Event Handler
    $('#next').on('click', nextSlide);// call function nextSlide

    // Prev Event Handler
    $('#prev').on('click', prevSlide);// call function prevSlide

    // Auto Slider Handler
    if(autoswitch == true){
        setInterval(nextSlide,autoswitch_speed);// call function and value 4000
    }

    // Switch to next slide
    function nextSlide(){
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')){
            $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
    // Delay removal of .oldActive until it is off-screen
    $('.oldActive').delay(1500).queue(function(next){
      $(this).removeClass("oldActive");
      next();
    });
        $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
    }

    // Switch to prev slide
    function prevSlide(){
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if($('.oldActive').is(':first-child')){
            $('.slide').last().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
        }
    // Delay removal of .oldActive until it is off-screen
        $('.oldActive').delay(1500).queue(function(next){
      $(this).removeClass("oldActive");
      next();
    });
        $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clearInterval()` to do this. You should clear the interval that you have defined before when the `nextSlide()` and `prevSlide()` functions are being called. After clearing the interval you should again call `setInterval()`. I have did the changes to your code to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // options
    var speed = 1000; //transition speed - fade
    var autoswitch = true; //auto slider options
    var autoswitch_speed = 8000; //auto slider speed
    let interval;

    // add first initial active class
    $(".slide").first().addClass("active");

    // hide all slides
    $(".slide").hide;

    // show only active class slide
    $(".active").show();

    // Next Event Handler
    $('#next').on('click', nextSlide);// call function nextSlide

    // Prev Event Handler
    $('#prev').on('click', prevSlide);// call function prevSlide

    // Auto Slider Handler
    if(autoswitch == true){
        interval = setInterval(nextSlide,autoswitch_speed);// call function and value 4000
    }
  
  function resetInterval() {
    if(autoswitch === true && interval !== null) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = setInterval(nextSlide,autoswitch_speed);// call 
    }
  }

    // Switch to next slide
    function nextSlide(){
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')){
            $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
    // Delay removal of .oldActive until it is off-screen
    $('.oldActive').delay(1500).queue(function(next){
      $(this).removeClass("oldActive");
      next();
    });
        $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
        resetInterval()
    }

    // Switch to prev slide
    function prevSlide(){
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if($('.oldActive').is(':first-child')){
            $('.slide').last().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
        }
    // Delay removal of .oldActive until it is off-screen
        $('.oldActive').delay(1500).queue(function(next){
      $(this).removeClass("oldActive");
      next();
    });
        $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
       resetInterval()
    }
});
```